# How do I extract this value using PHP Dom

Tags: php, dom

I do have html file this is just a prt of it though...

```
<div id="result" >
    <div class="res_item" id="1" h="63c2c439b62a096eb3387f88465d36d0">
        <div class="res_main">
            <h2 class="res_main_top">
                <img 
                    src="/ff/gigablast.com.png" 
                    alt="favicon for gigablast.com" 
                    width=16 
                    height=16
                    />&nbsp;
                <a 
                    href="http://www.gigablast.com/" 
                    rel="nofollow"
                    >
                    Gigablast
                </a>
                <div class="res_main">
                    <h2 class="res_main_top">
                        <img 
                            src="/ff/ask.com.png" 
                            alt="favicon for ask.com" 
                            width=16 
                            height=16
                            />&nbsp;
                        <a 
                            href="http://ask.com/" rel="nofollow"
                            >
                            Ask.com - What&#039;s Your Question?
                        </a>....
```

I want extract only url address (for example: `http://www.gigablast.com` and `http://ask.com/` - there are atleast 10 urls in that html) from above using PHP Dom Document..I know up to this but dont know how to move ahead??

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('urllist.html');

$data = $doc->getElementById('result');
```

then what?? this is inside tag hence I cant use `$data->getElementsByTagName()` here!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath to narrow down the field to `a` elements inside the `<div class="res_main">` element:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('urllist.html');
$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);

$query = '//div[@class="res_main"]//a';
$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

$urls = array();

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $href = $node->getAttribute('href');
    if (!empty($href)) {
        $urls[] = $href;
    }
}
```

This solves the problem of picking up all the `<a>` elements inside of the document, since it allows you to filter only the ones you want (since you don't care about navigation links, etc)...

Comment: great idea ..thanks man well I need to learn a lot ..I know  I am just beginer

Comment: there is one problem!! with this code I am getting empty space while I am doing implode fuction. for example http://google.com,,,,http://ask.com,,,,http://bing.com,,,,,etc...

Comment: Do you have links with empty `href=""` attributes?  You could add a clause to check for empty links (I'll edit that in)...

Comment: yeah there is...oops thats why

Comment: yeah thats great it works...I wasnt aware of an empty fuction can add like this....well thanks...one last question...how I can filter result more?? now I am getting result http://google.com,search-google.com,http://bing.com,search-bing.com....etc. I want eliminate search-google.com and other urls which start from "search"...how this can be possible??

Comment: Just add a check: `if (strpos($href, 'search') !== false) {` (which would execute if it finds `search` inside of the string)...

Comment: where do I add do I need to add in between loops

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getElementsByTagName` on a DOMElement object:

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('urllist.html');

$result = $doc->getElementById('result');
$anchors = $result->getElementsByTagName('a');

$urls = array();
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    $urls[] = $a->getAttribute('href');
}
```

If you want to get image sources as well, that would be easy to add.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to extract the `href` attribute of all `a` tags in the document (and the `<div id="result">` doesn't matter, you could use this:

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('urllist.html');
$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
$urls = array();
foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    $urls[] = $anchor->attributes->href;
}

// $urls is your collection of urls in the original document.
```